# .htaccess Rewrite rule to add word in URL in a specific group of URLs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I created some posts on my WordPress website but after some time I changed their URLs. The problem is that Google is still indexing the old ones so I would need a redirect while the change is not all done.

I only need this in a group of URLs.

What I need is to redirect all URLs starting with:

http://www.telesgotos.pt/inspecao-video- + the requested location (for example: telesgotos.pt/inspecao-video-lisboa)

to

http://www.telesgotos.pt/inspecao-de-video- + the requested location (same example: telesgotos.pt/inspecao-de-video-lisboa)

I've searched several similar questions but I don't know .htaccess syntax at all so I don't know how to target the first part of the URL, add the needed word and append the rest of the URL...

Thank you in advance!

Regards,
Ricardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `/.htaccess` file, insert the following just below `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteRule ^inspecao-video-lisboa/?$ /inspecao-de-video-lisboa [R=301,L]
```

If you don't want to be specific, then use this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^inspecao-video-(\w+)/?$ /inspecao-de-video-$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi! I tried it but it didn't work... This code redirects from /inspecao-video-example to /inspecao-de-video-example right?

Comment: The second rule will do that... Did you use that one?

Comment: Sorry! I inserted it in the wrong place... It works great! Thank you! :)

Comment: By the way, if there are several rewrite rules, should they be placed all in the same place as this one? Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. It depends on what those rules are and if they'll conflict somewhere along the lines. If the rules are similar, try keep them together.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that! :) Thank you Mike!